# JQuery pause slideshow and resume with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, carousel

I'm aware there's plenty of JQuery slideshows out there but I'm coding my own and have come across an obstacle I've not found an answer to specifically.

Background: An automated JQuery Slideshow plugin with pause/resume on hover/out

Problem: How to pause the slideshow on mousenter, and then finish the remaining time period of  the setInterval on mouseleave instead of firing the setInterval again.

Solution: I think the only way to do this would be to use a self-invoking method with a delay attached and a stop() to handle the mouse behaviour which would allow the paused animation to resume for its proper remainder rather than firing the method again?

What are your thoughts?

Here's the code:

```
    (function( $ ){

    var methods = {

        init: function() {

            var cycle = window.setInterval(methods.automate, 1000);

            $('.slider_control').on('click', 'span', function(){
                methods.automate( $(this).attr('slideNumber') );
            });

            $('.slider_master_container')
                .on({
                        'mouseenter': function() {
                            clearInterval(cycle);
                        },
                        'mouseleave': function() {
                            cycle = window.setInterval(methods.automate, 1000);
                        }
                });

        },

        automate: function( el ) {
            var $active = $('.slide.active'),
                $next   = el ? $('.slide[slideNumber=' + el) : $active.nextOrFirst();
            $next.css('z-index', 2);
            $active.fadeOut(1500, function() {
                $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active');
                $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active');
            });
        }

    };

    $.fn.smartSlider = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.smartSlider' );
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: NB: You'll need the nextOrFirst JQuery plugin if you want to run this code.

Comment: I believe the easiest way to do this would be to set `.attr("hover","on")` in the active slide on mouseover and clear it on mouseout, and when you hit the automate function, if this is set, `return;` out of the function.